# Rcpp with structured library in /src

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to write a wrapper for a C++ function I've written, making use of the Point Clouds Library (PCL). This is my first try interfacing R and C++, so I apologise if any solution is too trivial. My goal is to make a few functions available for myself and my colleagues directly in R, on **mac and windows**. My example function `cloudSize` is included at the bottom of the text. I will try to be as clear as possible.

I've installed PCL with the vcpkg package manager for winx64 at `C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg`.
This is added to my Environmental Variable Path for my user.

I created an empty R-package with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`:
`C:/User/csvi0001/Desktop/GitHub/RPCLpackage/PCLR`

PCL is a massive library, but thankfully modular,and so I only #include the headers that are needed to compile the executable: `pcl/io/pcd_io.h`, `pcl/point_types.h`, `pcl/registration/icp.h`.

Now, since I'd like this to work on more than one OS - and therefore compile on install (?) - I should use a dynamic library? I'll presume that the person installing my package already has a compiled copy of pcl. However, I do not know how to find a flag showing that pcl is installed - how do I find these for inclusion in Makevars(?). CMake must find them when testing the C++ function in VSCode after adding an include path. In lieu of this:

I copy the pcl folder installed by vcpkg to ./src . When I tried copying all the .h files, they seemed to lose track of one another as they refer to eachother through which module they are placed in, e.g. <pcl/memory.h> cannot be found if memory.h is placed directly in ./src. However, flattening the structure of the modules means that every single dependency and #include must be manually changed, in some cases there are also files with the same name in different folders. e.g. pcl/kdtree.h and pcl/search/kdtree.h. After this, it must be done again when replacing < > with " " for each header.

**Is there any way of telling Rcpp that the library included in /src is structured?**

I'm working on Win 10 winx64.

Since I'm making use of the depends RcppEigen and BH; and I must have C++14 or higher (choice: C++17) I add to my DESCRIPTION file:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppEigen, BH
SystemRequirements: C++17
```

My actual C++ function:

```
//PCL requires at least C++14
//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
//[[Rcpp::depends(BH)]] 

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "pcl/io/pcd_io.h"
#include "pcl/point_types.h"
#include "pcl/registration/icp.h"

//[[Rcpp::export]]
int cloudSize(Rcpp::DataFrame x)
{
  
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> sourceCloud;
  for(int i=0;i<x.nrows();i++)
  {
    sourceCloud.push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(x[0][i],x[1][i],x[2][i])); //This way of referring to elements in a Rcpp::DataFrame may be erroneous.
  }
  
  int cloudSize = sourceCloud->size();
        
    
 return (cloudSize);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a non-trivial question. In the simplest case, use a 'hook' offered by `configure` and `configure.win` to pre-build a (static) library you ship in your sources and then link your package to that.

That said, the [*Writing R Extensions*](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/) manual and/or the [*CRAN Repository Policy*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) (both of which are *the* references here) expressed more of a preference for an *external* library -- which may not be an option here if PCL is too exotic.

As the topic comes up with Rcpp, I wrote a short paper about it (at arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416)) which is also included as a [vignette in the package](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf). It requires a few pages to cover the common cases but even then it cannot cover all.

Your main source of reference may be CRAN. The are *lots* of packages in this space. A few of mine use external libraries, I contributed to package `nloptr` which uses a hybrid approach ("use system library if found, else build") and some like `httpuv` always build (a small-ish library).

Comment: Thank you Dirk, for your kind comment. Configure and Makefiles are still new to me. I'll have to look more into learning CMake flags, and work via external file writing until I can put together a better solution. Many thanks.